# Regular matrix and linear transformation map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $A$ be a matrix with dimension $n\times n$ , $B$ is a matrix with dimension $m\times m$ then if $f : R \to R$ where $R$ is the set of matrix with dimension $m\times n$ and $f(C) = ACB$ is isomorphism linear map then $A$ , $B$ are regular matrix

Edit:
If $f$ is isomorphism then $f^{-1}$ is isomorphism which equal to $(ACB)^{-1}$ so $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist then $A$ and $B$ are regular , right ?

Comment: Note that askers are expected to include context with their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to include the following. Where did you find this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The map $f$ can be viewed as $$M_{m\times n}\overset{\cdot B}{\longrightarrow}M_{m\times n}\overset{A \cdot}{\longrightarrow}M_{m\times n},$$
or
$$M_{m\times n}\overset{A \cdot}{\longrightarrow}M_{m\times n}\overset{ \cdot B}{\longrightarrow}M_{m\times n},$$
Then, if $f$ is a linear isomorphism, then the two maps $"\cdot B"$ and $"A\cdot"$ are injective, which implies that the rows of $B$ are linearly independent and columns of $A$ are linearly independent, thus $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular.

Comment: I don't understand ..

Comment: The notation $"A\cdot"$ means left multiplication by $A$, and $"\cdot B"$ means that right multiplication by $B$.

Comment: it mean that the function f is composition of A. and .B and since f is isomorphism then the two composition map are isomorphism then how you said A and B non-singular matrix

Comment: $"A\cdot"$ is injective, thus $AC=0$ implies $C=0$, so that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, thus $A$ is nonsingular. Similar for $\cdot B$.

Comment: if f = h o g isomorphism then h and g are too ?

Comment: $f=h\circ g$  isomorphism implies that $g$ is injective and $h$ is surjective. Here we just need the injectivity of the two multiplications.

Comment: So we can just conclude that A. injective but what about B i know i can change f but there will be a problem